# Vagaro React Embed

Tags: reactjs, embed

I am trying to embed a Vagaro form into a React project. I am having some troubles with it not fully loading it. In a plain HTML file, it all works smoothly so I know that their stuff works. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
function VagaroBooking() {
  const instanceRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = "https://www.vagaro.com//resources/WidgetEmbeddedLoader/OZqnDJ0pDJ0cT3qmV35y6JuPlXiz3avV34mC2PeFJ4mC30m9cyUeJUtjP0dDxkJEvwRapWUep2sERAJDXwOapcUd9eR71aRcXc?v=u0P6Q6fN3suUjyj8Tk6ON1Rltk3OWXZszbQKCMwAcbO#"
    script.async = true
    instanceRef.current.appendChild(script)

    return () => {
      const currentInstanceRef = instanceRef.current
      currentInstanceRef.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="frameTitle" className="embedded-widget-title">
        Book Now
      </div>
      <div ref={instanceRef} className="vagaro"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VagaroBooking
```